# Interface Callback from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to create an Interface call back from an Activity to a Fragment.  When I use create method setListener, this.value is set to equal the listener from the fragment.  When the activity gets to onCreate, the value becomes null.  I am not sure why I would have an object and suddenly the object is back to null.  What am I doing wrong in my implementation? Is there a better way to send data (just an integer) from an Activity to a Fragment?

I have tested and verified that the object exists in the setListener method and is then null in onCreate method of the activity.

Here is some code

This is in Activity:

My interface

```
 public interface onVendorMultiVendorComplete {
        void mIndex(int index);
    }
```

My listener object and my setListener method

```
private onVendorMultiVendorComplete vendorCallback;

public void setListener(onVendorMultiVendorComplete vendorCallback){
    this.vendorCallback = vendorCallback;
    //this.vendorCallback is object multi_vendor_show_vendor{c0d1486 #0 id=0x7f080092}

    //vendorCallback is object multi_vendor_show_vendor{c0d1486 #0 id=0x7f080092}
}
```

My method call on the interface

```
slideView.setOnSlideCompleteListener(new SlideView.OnSlideCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSlideComplete(SlideView slideView) {
                if (vendorCallback != null){ //vendorCallback is null
                    vendorCallback.mIndex(index);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is inside the fragment

First I implement onVendorMultiVendorComplete from Activity

I define my callback object

```
private multi_vendor_at_vendor vendorCallback;
```

I call setListener from multi_vendor_at_vendor (Activity) and pass it required arguments (being this)

```
vendorCallback.setListener(this);
```

I also override the necessary method from interface

```
@Override
public void mIndex(int index) {
    // This block of code is never ran because listener is null in activity
    jsonArray.remove(index);
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I expect for the listener object to not be null.

Comment: Figured I would clean and rebuild.  No change.  I also invalidated cache and restarted studio - still no change.

Comment: I think I found out why it is happening, not sure how to fix it.

The fragment is created, setListener Object is instantiated when fragment is attached.  The activity is started based on user interaction and the object vendorCallback is created again as null (private onVendorMultiVendorComplete vendorCallback;)

Shouldn't the vendorCallback object set by the fragment still exist though?

Comment: This case may occur when the object is re-created. Can you check fragments hashcode on setting the listener and where listener will be used? This hashcodes must be equals, but otherwise you can check where yor fragment has been recreated.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I ended up just going the EventBus route.  It is easier but can get messy with a lot of registers etc.  I am still unsure why the activity is recreated other than perhaps because I was accessing this activity via Intent with a recyclerview inside the fragment.